# MVC can't find my Areas page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created an Area in my application named Admin. It's pretty basic, looks like this:

- Areas

  - Admin

    - Controllers

      - CompaniesController.cs
    - Models
    - Views

      - Companies

        - Index.aspx
    - AdminAreaRegistration.cs

When I try to view my Index page by going to /Admin/Companies, I get a "The resource cannot be found" message. I find it weird that I don't get any sort of error message.

I'm not sure what's going on here, has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you newly created Index.aspx, you need to "REBUILD" the solution or your web project. Build only compile your last changes and rebuild build everything from the scratch. I faced that problem when I started writing Asp.net MVC project.

Does it solve your problem?